# Ubuntu: reboot if / mounted readonly due to errors=remount-ro

Tags: bash, ubuntu, readonly, mount

Problem: We generally face a problem where ubuntu os gets mounted readonly. Reason is clear as mentioned in fstab on errors=remount-ro.

Question: Is there any mechanism to reboot the appliance if it comes to readonly mounted state.

Tried: I tried to write a script as below which will get monitored by watchdog. This works but it continuously reboot if script return exit 1 due to any mount point is still readonly. What i expect is to check if uptime if less then a day then it should not reboot even though any mount point is readonly?

`root@ubuntu1404:/home/ubuntu# cat /rofscheck.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

now=`date`
echo "------------"
echo "start : ${now}"
up_time=`awk '{print int($1)}' /proc/uptime`

#if uptime is less than 1 day then skip test
if [ "$up_time" -lt 86400 ]; then
    echo "uptime is less ${now}, exit due to uptime"
    exit 0
fi
grep -q ' ro' /proc/mounts > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 0

# alert watchdog that fs is readonly.
exit 1
```

Now in /etc/watchdog.conf below config is done.

```
test-binary = /rofscheck.sh
```

To reproduce the problem to mount readonly all mounted fs, ran this:

$ `echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

which does emergency remount readonly.

Comment: If the system mounts a file system read only, this means the file system may contain errors. It is necessary to fix the errors, before you can continue to use the file system. Ubuntu can not fix the errors alone and likewise it is not wise to think this errors can be fixed automatically without human interaction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [unix.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

this script worked for me, even if it is much similar to yours.
I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with latest updates.

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date)
up_time=$(awk '{print int($1)}' /proc/uptime)
min_time=7200

#if uptime is less than 2 hours then skip test
if [ ${up_time} -lt ${min_time} ]; then
    echo "uptime is ${up_time} secs, less than ${min_time} secs (now is ${now}): exit 0 due to uptime"
    exit 0
fi

exit=$(grep ' ro,' /proc/mounts | wc -l)
if [ ${exit} -gt 0 ]; then
        exit 1
else
        exit 0
fi
```

Please note that I have setup the minimum time as a variable, adjust it at your convenience.

A small important notice:
I am using this solution on a very cheap couple of cloud servers I own that I use for testing purposes only.
I have also setup filesystem check at every reboot with the following command:

`tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda1`

I would never use this kind of watchdog usage in a production environment.

Hope this helps.
Best regards.